# Another way to write, ''Why now''? When people know it is good, but are suspicious of the timing)

Tags: expressions

Another way to write, ''Why now''? (When people know it is good, but are suspicious of the timing)

Comment: Why do you not want to use the concise and accurate "Why now?"?

Comment: You can suggest an alternate time, e.g. _What's wrong with tomorrow?_

Comment: I hardly dare to propose "*Why not later?*"

Comment: Although “[what’s the rush](http://www.bu.edu/questrom/2010/02/22/stakeholder-orientation-whats-the-rush-qa/)” is often used together with “Why now” (“Why now, what’s the rush?”), you could certainly use it by itself (“What’s  the rush?”/ “Why the rush?”) to question the timing.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that I've seen writers take is to identify the fortuitous event, spell out its benefits to the public (voters, employees, or whoever else), and note any advantage that its occurring at this particular moment might have for people in positions of decision-making power (incumbent politicians, embattled corporate executives, or others who may have a vested interest in the outcome)—and then conclude with the one-word question, "Coincidence?"

Here is a fictitious example:

> After months of delays in responding to demands by citizens for street repairs, Mayor Blaine Blintz today announced authorization of large-scale repairs on several important roadways. Construction, which should be complete approximately three weeks before scheduled municipal elections take place, will include resurfacing of major thoroughfares running through several neighborhoods where allies of the mayor are in close contests for reelection. Coincidence?